# Include GMOCK lib to VS 2017 test(GTEST) workspace giving linker redefinition error with gtest.lin in gmock?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to use GMOCK in VS 2017 GTEST project, it is giving  already defined in gmock.lib(gtest-all.obj) errors for gtest.lib.

May be VS2017 GTEST and GMOCK both including gtest.lib, which is causing the issue?

is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of error you get? Please copy and paste full error message.

Comment: Error LNK2005 "bool testing::internal::g_help_flag" (?g_help_flag@internal@testing@@3_NA) already defined in gmock.lib(gtest-all.obj) Sample-Test1 D:\test\UnitTest17\ConsoleApplication1\Sample-Test1\gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)                                                                                          
             Like the above error 377 error are there( already defined)